# Can I use nested scoping when specifying environments in ConfigSlurper?

Tags: groovy

Using Groovy 2.0.7, when I have a config.groovy such as:-

```
def configText = """
switch(environment) {
    case 'localhost':
        PROXY {
            HOST = "localproxy"
        }
    break
}

PROXY {
    HOST = "defaultproxy"
}"""

def config = new ConfigSlurper("localhost").parse(configText)
```

, I get an assertion failure when I do this:-

```
assert "localproxy" == config.PROXY.HOST
```

If I remove the "defaultproxy" line then the environment value is correctly returned.

Am I doing something wrong? This to me is a standard requirement, to have a default value specified for config.PROXY.HOST but be able to override it in the environments  switch block.

I know I can use the environments constructor to override the values but that is no use to me as it doesn't allow me to evaluate  values, e.g. if I had:-

```
PROXY {
    HOST = "defaultproxy"
    URL = "http://" + HOST
}
```

then the URL would always be `http://defaultproxy` even if I specified the "localhost" environment.

I need the features from both really! Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also put the switch statement after the default proxy.host property...

```
def configText = """
PROXY {
    HOST = "defaultproxy"
}
switch(environment) {
    case 'localhost':
        PROXY {
            HOST = "localproxy"
        }
    break
}
"""

def config = new ConfigSlurper("localhost").parse(configText)
assert "localproxy" == config.PROXY.HOST
```

or you could leverage the environment property like this:

```
def configText = """
    PROXY {
        HOST = "defaultproxy"
    }
    environments{
        localhost{
            PROXY.HOST='localproxy'
        }
    }
    """

def config = new ConfigSlurper("localhost").parse(configText)
assert "localproxy" == config.PROXY.HOST
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have a solution which works.

I wrapped the switch statement into a function, then called the function at the top of the script (below the function, above the nested scoped properties) and then called the function again at the bottom.

Crude, horrible, but works. If anyone has a better solution, please let me know!